# How can I read a .txt in a string.xml file?

Tags: java, android, xml, string

I have a long text that I need to put into strings and so far it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="long_text">
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
</string>
</resources>
```

And it looks bad. Besides, if I want to change the text, it is a bit inconvenient. So I would like to have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="long_text"> assets/myfile.txt </string>
</resources>
```

That long xxx text would be stored in a file - myfile.txt - somewhere in the folder. I've seen some solutions where the text is inserted through the java code, rather than strings.xml, but it is way too complicated for me. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You could possibly use this strategy and place the big text in an individual file: https://alvinalexander.com/android/how-to-store-static-text-in-android-file-res-values

Comment: I actually had that page opened, but I don't really know how to use a file instead of that HTML code. Would <a href> work?

Comment: Replace the HTML with `<![CDATA[ your document text]]>` if it's just text data you can do all the big text in that one file alone, anchored by XML tags, rather than have it in a shared strings.xml file.

Comment: You mean, instead of having string.xml to have longtext.xml with that CDATA code and text? The problem is that I have two translations and I have string.xml for two different languages. Won't longtext.xml be only for one language?

Comment: Okay. I tried your method and it worked. I added the longtext.xml in the folder corresponding to each language and it worked. Thank you for the help! I would gladly select your answer as the best answer, if you are planning to write one. It might be helpful also for the others.

Comment: This is a bad approach, use `<![CDATA[ your document text]]>` as @Compass suggested. Currently, you have a perfectly usable stand-alone XML file that can be consumed by any system without relying on those extra `assets` files. Once you put long content into external files, the whole purpose of the XML file changes from being the source of data, to simply pointing to sources of data which could or could not be present on that system. Also, "it looks bad" comment is not a real concern because XML files aren't meant to look good, they are for computers to process, not for people to marvel at.

Comment: I agree with @SergeyB assessment. It's basically using strings as a "data source" rather than as a "text source." I wrote out the entire answer specific to your problem and documented the pitfalls that your implementation method could cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution based heavily on the implementation provided by: https://alvinalexander.com/android/how-to-store-static-text-in-android-file-res-values

You can create a standalone resource outside of the *strings.xml* file if you're concerned about managing a massive block of text. This limits typos to a single file, i.e. if you forget a bracket somewhere it will isolate to a specific XML document.

Create an XML file in *res/values* called *strings_longtext.xml* and place the single text value in there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="very_large_string">
        <![CDATA[
            Lorem ipsum
            Lorem ipsum
            Lorem ipsum
            Lorem ipsum
            Lorem ipsum
            Lorem ipsum             
        ]]>
    </string>
</resources>
```

You can then access this string through a context accessor similar to a normal *strings.xml* file.

```
context.getString(R.string.very_large_string);
```

The reason you should not be putting file names in *strings.xml* is multifold:

- Changes values of strings as being actual text values to being file references that need to be parsed and processed
- Can be inadvertently broken in i18n efforts through carelessness or automation
- code/version management exists outside a defined resources directory

The purpose of *strings* files is for pure application-based text; adding file name interpretation to it is code smell and will cause a painful breakdown as the project gets larger, especially if the files exist outside the standard project structure.