# String file importing content from external file (txt/xls/pdf/...)

Tags: xml, string, external

Trying to get my string.xml file to source it's content from an external one.

I tried [to this in-house thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956685/how-can-i-read-a-txt-in-a-string-xml-file), but no help.

Thanks for the code examples and all actual help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 suggestions you could consider (I use all of them, in different circumstances).

1. Use external parsed entities defined in a DTD.
2. Use XInclude.
3. Use a processing instruction such as `<?include some.txt?>` which you expand using an XSLT stylesheet.

By the way, only your first sentence is describing your problem, and it's not a very detailed description of what you want to achieve. The following five paragraphs are largely concerned with expressing your level of frustration, and should be deleted.

Comment: *Edited* Hmm. Example? I tried a few different ways, bit for some reason strings only want to be loaded in with the @string bit.

Comment: My general approach to answering a question like this is to point you in the right direction, not to hold your hand and walk you to the destination. That's especially true when your question gives very little detail of your requirements. If you try one of these appproaches and can't make it work, raise a new question with specific details of what you did and how it failed.